# UIView created in a GCD global queue odd behavior after added as a subview

Tags: ios

I'm creating some UIViews and caching them for reasons that aren't really important to the question at hand.

After I add the view X as a subview to Y one of X's subviews does not appear. If I wait 20-30 seconds it suddenly appears.

Here's how I am creating the views and adding them to the cache. These views are not yet added to the ui, that happens later.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{

        for(int i = 0; i < 10;i++){
            MyUIView *cTemp = [[MyUIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
            [self addViewToCahce:cTemp forKey:@"key"];  

        }

});
```

but if I remove the `dispatch_async` it appears as it should. Anyone know what is going on here or how to prevent this unusual behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Never modify UI outside of the main thread. Cocoa, like most UI frameworks, is not multithreaded. Try the following instead:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
    // Do whatever processing you want to do here
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        for(int i = 0; i < 10;i++){
            MyUIView *cTemp = [[MyUIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
            [self addViewToCahce:cTemp forKey:@"key"];  

        }
    });    
});
```

As for why you experience the behavior you describe, I can only speculate. I would not trust the constructor to `UIView` to be thread safe. If you need to create your views in another thread, I would suggest refactoring the code a bit, if possible.

Comment: Yes, this :-D as soon as I saw the title I was thinking this.

Comment: Ok I'll try your changes and see what happens. The views aren't added to the UI during that loop, they are added later during cell creation in the tableviews `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, is that still considered modifying the UI outside the main thread? 

The reason I want to thread the creation is because the views are created at app start and the app hangs for 0.5-1 second on a black screen if its not threaded.

Comment: Try to defer the creation of the cells until requested by `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Use the `reuseIdentifier` to create only as many cells as needed. Offload the loading of data to cache if that is slow, but you should try to keep that away from the view/cell itself.

Comment: Ah well, the design calls for dynamic cell content so I can't use a single xib and reuse it. To account for this I'm using the standard tableview reusable cells for the base of the view then using a secondary reusable view cache for internal cell subviews. So at most there are 3 tableview cells and 10 internal subviews. The cache in the question above is for the internal subviews and the subview are taking 0.25-0.5 seconds to be created, hence the need for the threaded view creation before the tableview asks for a cell.

Comment: I would still suggest you try to offload just the creation of the cache - without the creation of views - to the thread. Then create the views with reading pure data (no UI) from the cache.